# Provide sum totals from within column, move to the next title name on same row column, copy paste

Tags: excel, vba

Very new at complex Macro's, my question is the following. I have column titles within excel sheet1, I am trying to copy all (Total SUM) data into "Sheet2"; several of the columns have merged columns, I am looking to have my macro read the last row title on column C38 and match the copy the total SUM on F38.

Example: Macro is suppose to read the title column, Row C38 with title "Total Assets" on column C and  then search for the provided total on column F38, however, columns F, G, H are currently merged, F20 across F38,G38,H38.

After move down the empty Row, search for the next different title name, such like, "Total Funds" and repeat the process. I tried with 2 different scripts.  Listed below I have provided my macro scripts.  Perhaps, there is a better way at gathering all data per column.

Macro script:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[18]C[-3],R[3]C[-3]:R[18]C[8],4,FALSE)"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are asking as I don't see a question and you're also saying row or column when talking about specific cells, which only causes confusion. Are you looking for code that copies cell C38 from Sheet1 to Sheet2 if the contents of cells C38 and F38 on Sheet1 match?

Comment: Macro would first need to read column "C" search for Total Amount on column "F38', then move one single row down to continue searching for the next title row named "Other Assets" then search for "Total Other Assets" within row "F45". Column C has 8 different "Totals" with name titles, listed through totals on column F90. Each Total would need to be copied from Sheet1, set on a Sheet2 layout report.

Comment: You are still mixing column, row and cell: F38 is a cell, so are F45 and F90. F is the column, 38, 45 and 90 are the rows.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I meant to say "Rows"

Comment: F is the column, 38,45,and 90 are the rows with totals.

Comment: So you have 3 totals you want to copy to another sheet? F38, F45 and F90?

Comment: Yes, 3 totals, I would need to copy into another sheet. F38, F45, F90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they stay the same you don't need VBA to do it, simply put `=Sheet1!F38`, `=Sheet1!F45` and `=Sheet1!F90` in the corresponding cells on Sheet2.

If they are variable you can loop over the cells of Sheet1 searching for your titels like this (if I understood it correctly):

```
Sub CopyFromSheet1()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 to Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' Last Cell of Column F
        Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value) ' Looks at the Value in Column C
        Case "Total Amount"
            Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Case "Other Assets"
            Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Case "Total Other Assets"
            Sheet2.Cells(3, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

This loop is looking at the values in column C, if it matches "Total Amount", "Other Assets" or "Total Other Assets" in copies the values of that row from column F of `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` into cells "A1", "A2" and "A3" respectively. In this code `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` refer to the `CodeName` of the sheets.

Comment: Unfortunately they do not stay the same, so, simply =Sheet1!F38, =Sheet1!F45 and =Sheet1!F90 in the corresponding cells on Sheet2 would not work..

Comment: With your script, I get  Run-time error '13':   Type mismatch

Comment: @Robert-Macro Try it now with the added `CStr()` function

Comment: Highlights in yellow:  Case "Total amount"

Comment: I either messed up the `Select Case` or you need to add error handling in case your column C contains errors or other not string convertible values

Comment: It worked. Thank you! However, there is more to this report within Rows, I will continue testing script.

Comment: Actual system report "Sheet1" apparently has some sort of misaligned data rows, and several columns need to be set to Unmerge cells.

Comment: Question, What if column C, D, E moving across has "Total Amount", "Other Assets" or "Total Other Assets" and all I need is the numbers down each row?

Comment: `Cells( ROW , COLUMN )` is the syntax for the `Cells()` method.

Comment: Thank you for answering question.